# VTK Render Mouse Interaction (Python)

Tags: python, camera, controls, vtk

I want to visualize one or more STL file(s) using a vtk render viewport inside my application. I was able to get it all running with this example here: https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/IO/ReadSTL/

My question is as follows: I have a mouse to control it and it is just unbelievable how bad default the controls of the camera are. It is almost impossible to get the model rotated intentionally or focus on a certain part. I am confused as I could not find any topic here or elsewhere discussing this. Normally I would read through other threads to find an answer, but there doesn't seem to be any. So, maybe you can point me to an approach or even certain functions of how I can change these settings, that would be really great! Basically I want to mimic the camera behavior of say, Paraview or a common CAD tool. Like zooming with mouse wheel, rotating with RMB and holding down the wheel to pan.

Some background on my project: I have written a python program and created a quite ok UI using tkinter. However, recently I was thinking of rewriting some basic parts of it and also upgrading everything visually and in terms of handling. So, I want to move to Qt widgets and, there shall be a VTK rendering viewport inside my application to show some of the stuff that can be interacted with.

Comment: No answers so far, I guess I asked something too obvious. I am going to have a deeper look at the tutorials and update this post as soon as I found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution in the tutorials. By explicitly defining the vtkInteractorStyle with
style = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera()
The handling is just as I wanted it to be.